# Conditional aggregate for a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, pyspark

I am trying to perform a conditional aggregate on a PySpark data frame.

I tried sum/avg, which seem to work correctly, but somehow the count gives wrong results.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('a', '1', 2502, 332), 
                              ('b', '1', 2328, 56),
                              ('a', '1', 21, 78),
                              ('b', '2', 234, 23),
                              ('b', '2', 785, 12)
                             ],
                             ['x','id', 'y','z'])
df.show()

+---+---+----+---+
|  x| id|   y|  z|
+---+---+----+---+
|  a|  1|2502|332|
|  b|  1|2328| 56|
|  a|  1|  21| 78|
|  b|  2| 234| 23|
|  b|  2| 785| 12|
+---+---+----+---+
```

```
df_new = df.groupBy("id").agg(
                        F.avg(F.when((F.col("x") == 'a'), F.col('y'))
                               .otherwise(0)).alias('col1'),

                        F.count(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), F.col('y'))
                                 .otherwise(0)).alias('col2'),

                        F.sum(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), F.col('y'))
                               .otherwise(0)).alias('col3')
    )
df_new.show()

+---+-----+----+----+
| id| col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|841.0|   3|2328|
|  2|  0.0|   2|1019|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

The count should ideally give `1`, `2` row-wise, as in the expected result is:

```
+---+-----+----+----+
| id| col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|841.0|   1|2328|
|  2|  0.0|   2|1019|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Because the second row is the only one that matches the criteria for `id='1'` and `x='b'`. But it shows 3 for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `.otherwise` from the `count`. since `0` will also increase count.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_new = df.groupBy("id").agg(
                        F.avg(F.when((F.col("x") == 'a'), F.col('y')).otherwise(0)).alias('col1'),

                        F.count(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), F.col('y'))).alias('col2'),

                        F.sum(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), F.col('y')).otherwise(0)).alias('col3')
    )

df_new.show()

+---+-----+----+----+
| id| col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|841.0|   1|2328|
|  2|  0.0|   2|1019|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Or use `sum` like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_new = df.groupBy("id").agg(
                        F.avg(F.when((F.col("x") == 'a'), F.col('y')).otherwise(0)).alias('col1'),

                        F.sum(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), 1).otherwise(0)).alias('col2'),

                        F.sum(F.when((F.col("x") == 'b'), F.col('y')).otherwise(0)).alias('col3')
    )

df_new.show()
+---+-----+----+----+
| id| col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|841.0|   1|2328|
|  2|  0.0|   2|1019|
+---+-----+----+----+
```